# Android paused state clarification

Tags: android, state, android-lifecycle

The [Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) states: "If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your activity), it is paused. A paused activity is completely alive (it maintains all state and member information and remains attached to the window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory situations."

Can someone give an example of "a new non-full-sized or transparent activity" that would cause an activity to enter the paused state?

I can't think of an example that would meet this criteria. It has always been my understanding that activities are full screen in nature. They can't be "non-full-sized" and a transparent activity would only have a transparent background, thus causing the an activity to enter the stopped state, not a paused one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an example would be an activity with the theme of a dialog.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

So the activity is the size of a dialog (not taking up the whole screen) but with all of the functionality of an activity

Comment: [from official source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)  "For example, when a semi-transparent activity opens (such as one in the style of a dialog), the previous activity pauses."